# Get label counter

Tags: cross-referencing, easylist

When I do `\ref{mylabel}` to refer item from `easylist`, I'm getting `3.`, so the numbering enumerate works fine. But I want just `3`... How can I get 
the numeric value, associated to this particular `mylabel`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
  & foo \label{myfoo}
  & bar
\end{easylist}

This is ref foo: \ref{myfoo}

This is value foo: \value{myfoo}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a Minimum Working Example (MWE). If you use `enumitem`, you can say, for example, `\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., ref=\arabic*]`. I've never used `easylist`.

Comment: Well, it's not about `easylist`, it's just about how to change `\ref` format. If I labeled something, how can I change `\ref{mylabel}` format?

Comment: `\ref{mylabel}` outputs `3.`, when `\value{mylabel}` outputs ` ` -- nothing... therefore, `\arabic\value{mylabel}` gives error, `Missing \endcsname inserted`

Comment: Why don't you provide an example? Your question is about `\ref{}` but the answer may depend on what happens when `\label{}` is used, which I assume depends on `easylist`. But whether it is about `easylist`, `\ref` or small furry creatures from Alpha Centauri, you should still provide an MWE. (Except that in the last case, your question would probably be off-topic.)

Comment: @Mico That won't work earlier or later, though, but only within the scope in which `\label{}` itself is used, right? After and before, the value will be different. Or are you talking about using that to write to the `.aux` file when `\label{}` is used?

Comment: @cfr thanks, I've add the example and result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41369/discussion-between-zarkone-and-cfr).

Comment: Thanks for adding some code. Can you make it compilable? That is much more helpful than a fragment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: `\value{enumi}` would give an error anyway and  `\number\value{enumi}` would just give the last enumi value of course, but not the one related to the `myfoo` label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The behaviour you show seems to be the intentional package default, but you can change it so that the final `.` is part of the label formatting not part of the counter style.

please always post complete documents which makes testing easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\newcommand\adddot[1]{#1.}
\ListProperties(CtrCom=\adddot,FinalMark=)
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
  & foo \label{myfoo}
  & bar
\end{easylist}

This is ref foo: \ref{myfoo}

%This is value foo: \value{myfoo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, David -- this is literally shame that I haven't take this option in account: seems like I just get too tired doing my dissertation

Answer (score 2):

It took a lot of effort to track down the counter name used by `easylist`!

The `\mylabel` macro can be used to store almost anything for recall by `\ref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}%
  {\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]% #1=name, #2 = contents
    {\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}%
      {\@currentlabelname}{\@currentHref}{}}}}}%
  {\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]% #1=name, #2 = contents
    {\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
  & foo \mylabel{myfoo}{\arabic{List1}}
  & bar
\end{easylist}

This is ref foo: \ref{myfoo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see, great! I've invented this: `\ListProperties=(Start1*=\theMyCounter,CtrCom=\mycnt)`,  where `\mycnt` print `MyCounter` as I want to and also `\refstepcounter` it. This `Start1*` is binding `MyCounter` as `easylist` counter, and this works for me to do refs